# Application background refresh issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, swift4.2

I am working on one application which is developed in swift. When application kept in background then it automatically refresh after some interval and when application is going into the foreground state from background state then application refresh. I read all about background refresh and then later disable background refresh from application. And also from device also. Still same issue raise.

[Xcode capabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZz9A.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're describing a feature, but what is exactly your issue?

Comment: I disable this feature still app is refreshing in background

Comment: Can you show any of your code to see what you're doing and where the problem might come from?

Comment: I simply disable background fetch from background modes

Comment: In the photo you show capabilities for _Release_. Do you experience the problem in _Debug_ mode, and what capabilities do you have enabled there?